# Java null pointer exception when i pass this three parameter to the lazy loading class

Tags: android, lazy-loading, nullpointerexception

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)   
    {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null)
        { 
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photodata,null);

            myHolder = new ViewHolder();
            try
            {  
                myHolder.imgPhoto = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgPhoto);            
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            convertView.setTag(myHolder);
        }
        else
        {
            myHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        System.out.println("String image is" + getItem(position).photo);
        myHolder.imgPhoto.setTag(getItem(position).photo);
        System.out.println("String image is" + getItem(position).photo);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(getItem(position).photo,activity, myHolder.imgPhoto);

        return convertView;
    }
```

Error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at.com.android.adapter.PhotoAdater.getView(PhotoAdater.java:59)
 at.android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
```

Comment: The 59 there represents (I believe) the line number where the exception was thrown. It should identify which variable(s) are the candidates to be null. You may also try debugging and placing a breakpoint there to verify why it's null if possible.

Comment: Is there a typo in `ViewHolder holder`, think the variable must be `myHolder`

Answer (score 1):

This code you are declaring ,

```
 ViewHolder holder;
```

but you are using different object,

```
myHolder.imgPhoto= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgPhoto);
```

change as,

```
 holder.imgPhoto= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgPhoto);
```

and also change Layoutinflater like this,

convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photodata,null,false);

this code reduced error

Comment: i am change holder instead of myHolder but still i get that error

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem in the code you have pasted here. Seeing the code I assume

```
  ViewHolder holder;
```

should actually be

```
  ViewHolder myHolder;
```

In that case, you have created the instance using `new` in the if condition, but in the `else`, it is not done. So ,`myHolder` points to `null`. Think this is the reason for the `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

My guess without line numbers and/or knowing what you're passing to this method...if you attempt to call this method with position == null then it will throw an NPE because you're passing null to a primitive.